# Flex layout issue - Angular Material table - not fit into div

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, responsive-design

I'm trying to create responsive layout with the help of `flex`. but i end up with inconsistent **height**. my **mat-table** height goes beyond the outer `div` when changing the **pagination**  value and overlapping below cards. I thought `overflow: auto` would help me but seems not.

i need to maintain **table height** inside the card and it should be responsive

here is the [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-euabq5?file=app%2Ftable-pagination-example.css)

current output

[image]

1. How add scrollbar(if possible slim) when pagination value changed
2. how maintain table height inside the card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `overflow-y: scroll;` to `.card-02` class. Here is a working code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-euabq5-g8jjgc?file=app/table-pagination-example.css

Comment: Ahh.. @TinsG thank you so much.. you saved me dude :)

Comment: instead of setting scroll to outer div.. how can we achieve the same for table?

Comment: yes, you can do that here you can find the updated https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-euabq5-g8jjgc?file=app/table-pagination-example.css

Comment: You're simple Awesome.. now the look and feel is so elegant... Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

just get a table from bootstrap and problem solved

Comment: I should use mat-table that's my requirement actually